# Choosing SDK version to reach maximum number of people

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am a complete beginner in Android Development and just downloaded Android SDK to integrate it with Eclipse.

However, I don't know which Android version I should select in SDK Manager to allow a maximum number of people to download and use my app.

Here's a screenshot of the manager that is showing up on my screen.

[image: SDK Manager window]

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Try Android 2.1 and let us know how it works to target the maximum amount of users ;). In all seriousness, that depends entirely on what features you're planning to use in your app. I'd say that targeting from 4.1 upwards is a safe bet since you'll have about 96% of Android users covered. See the platform usage statistics [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform).

Comment: The link you provided seems quite useful :)
Does "targeting from 4.1 upwards" means selecting all the versions above 4.1 or just any one of the versions above 4.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, you don't need to download an OLD SDK just to allow OLD Devices to use your app.

This is done in your project settings via target SDK version and min API level(AndroidManifest.xml or build.gradle).

**Define Audience**

First, define the audience to your app.

[HERE](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) you can find the market share  for every Android Version (this can change for each country but it may help).

If you check that table, you can see that only few devices are still using API 15 or older.

[image]

So, if you support API<15, you will only reach ~3% more people. If you can support them without lose any feature, good (not all android features are supported/ported to all versions). But if you may need to disable a feature (like that special Floating Action Button that you created) just to reach those devices, I think it does not worth.

**So, based on that table, you define the audience**

In my case for example, I like to build apps for devices with API from API_16 to API_24.

Usually, we always want to use maximum API available. Today, 24.

This way, I could reach ~97% of the people using Android.

But this is optional... I could select min API as 13... or 14.. or 4.. This is up to you..

**After defining the audience**

*Target SDK*

I usually set the target API according to the MAX API I want to support. So, for example, if the MAX API I want to support is API_24, this will be my target API and will download the SDK v24 (7.0).

Usually, you always will have the latest SDK installed since you always want to reach latest android version and enjoy all the new features.

*MIN API*

Now, you also have defined the min API version that you want to support. So, lets use API 16 for example (first JB version).

You will set this in your project file (`AndroidManifest.xml`). You don't need to download SDK 16 just because of that.

**Setting Eclipse**

As I said, min SDK will be set in your project. That would be done in your Android Manifest

Here, you can see that targetSdk is 24. It means that I just need to download SDK v24 to build this project. Even then, I'll be able to install this App in devices with API 16 or later.

*Eclipse (AndroidManifest.xml)*

```
<manifest>
    ....
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

*Android Studio (build.gradle)*

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

minSdkVersion "16"
targetSdkVersion "24"
```

**minSdkVersion Does Not Guarantee that your app will work**

Note that settings above only allow your app to run in devices with API>=16 or API<=24. However, your app may crash or does not work in all devices within that range. This usually happens because some View Components or Methods were added or removed according to API version.

For example, `Fragment` was added only on API11. So, if you try to install your app in a phone with APIv11, it will work. However, if you install it in a device with API4, it will crash.

Another example is method `Fragment.onAttach(Context context)` which was added only in API 23.

**That's why we use Support Library**

Support Design Library it is a library created by Google which enables the developer to use features from new Android Versions in old Android versions.

So, for example, to add a Fragment which is compatible with devices with API<11, you should import and use `Fragment` class from package `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of default version included in SDK (`android.app.Fragment`).

This way, your app wont crash.

Of course this is very basic example. It is just to illustrate...

Anyway, I hope I could help you
Regards

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer!
I now have a good idea about the use of all these Android Platforms :)

Comment: Glad I could help you... :)